# Asymptotic freedom of $O(n)$ models and mass gap

Tags: renormalization

In the analysis of renormalization group towards $O(3)$ spin model, it is claimed that **the asymptotic freedom of $O(n)$ models suggests that they develop a mass gap dynamically**. I have no intuition on this statement at all. Please give some physical and direct interpretation on this.